# Spring AMQP 1.3.5 correlation id

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp

Does anyone know why Spring Integration (AMQP 1.3.5) requires the correlation-id to be a byte array? Rabbit's AMQP-Client 3.3.5 takes a String for the correlation-id in the AMQP.BasicProperties class. Doesn't Spring need to convert the byte array to this String at some point? We're finding that the correlation-id in the message Rabbit sends is still a byte array, and is never converted to a String. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I have no insight; it was before my time on the project and it's a day one issue.

Spring AMQP converts the `byte[]` to a String in `DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter` (outbound); invoked by the `RabbitTemplate` using `UTF-8` by default. The resulting string is added to the `BasicProperties`.

On the listener container (inbound) side, UTF-8 is used unconditionally.

The rabbit client converts to `byte[]` when writing to the wire (in `ValueWriter.writeShortStr()`), unconditionally using charset `UTF-8`.

So, unless you change the charset in `RabbitTemplate` (which would be bad), it's a no-op (but unnecessary if you already have a `String`).

I can only speculate that, since `MessageProperties` is an abstraction (and not tied to RabbitMQ), some other client had it as a `byte[]` when the abstraction was being designed.

Since we only have a rabbitmq implementation, I wouldn't be averse to adding an optimization to the abstraction to avoid the unnecessary conversion.

Feel free to open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll take a look at it for the upcoming 1.5 release.